# Modular Abilities: If Link cannot connect a disadvantage to an advantage, how does one associate them?

Tags: gurps

I want to run a superhero game with Modular Abilities that trigger themed disadvantages. For example, the advantage "**Flight**" would trigger the disadvantage "*Cowardice*"; the advantage "**Damage Resistance**" would trigger the disadvantage "*Berserk*"; the advantage "**Telecommunication (Telesend)**" would trigger the disadvantage "*Truthfulness*"; the advantage "**Invisibility**" would trigger the disadvantage "*Kleptomania*."

On page 106 I see that "Link" is meant to link multiple advantages. Thus I need a rule to link a disadvantage to an advantage.  One approach might be to simply note that the two effects always go together and to deduct the points of the disadvantage from the advantage. Thus Telesend with Truthfulness would be 30-5 points for a total of 25 points.  I suspect that GURPS already has a canonical way of doing this, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Temporary Disadvantages

Linking is indeed for other purposes. What you should use is Temporary Disadvantages (B115) on the Advantages that you slot *into* your Modular Abilities. Yes, the savings aren't as impressive, and the system does them so on the assumption that you can easily avoid using those powers and thus don't suffer the usual downsides of a Disadvantage most of the time.

## Alternative Solution: Alternate Forms

This is a less intuitive way of solving your issue. If you think it's OK to spend 10 seconds switching between 'modes', or you're willing to fork over the points to make the switching relatively quick, and are either willing to put up with the other downsides, or, again, willing to pay for compensating them, you can opt to make different power suites as different Alternate Forms. It's probably not a good solution in your case, but it's one that's good to keep in mind if you ever end up with needing to slowly switch between big packages of both Advantages and Disadvantages.

Comment: The Temporary Disadvantage rule will be great for the good-guy player characters, but I plan to have them fighting werewolves and vampires soon, so I'll design the bad guy NPCs with Alternate Forms.  Thanks very much!